# Modal Changing its class name to seperate from another modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used bootstrap 4 to have modal,how can I separate their contents to by changing their class name? I have changed it and tried it but it show up of the same content because of the same class. I'm beginner of using bootstrap and used to create manual css. Now I have decided to adopt it to have a fast development.
I also used data tables which is very useful.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Launch demo modal
    </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save 
    changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The purpose of the class is so that it can be used on multiple elements. If you have multiple modals, each modal should have its own unique id, like: <div class="modal" id="uniqueModalId">, then your button should target that id, like, <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uniqueModalId">Open Modal</button>

Comment: @MichaelvE Thankyou so much. I thought the id I see in div modal is only for its js  functions.